# Repast Simphony Model Library

Tags: simulation, netlogo, repast-simphony

Is there any model library for Repast Simphony? I'm looking for something similar to the [Computational Model Library](https://www.comses.net/codebases/2261/releases/1.0.0/) of OpenABM. Unfortunatelly, there are only models for NetLogo but not for Repast in this library. (In particular, I'm searching for a scientific paper using agent based simulation for studying innovation diffusion processes and a corresponding model in Repast I can download. The idea in behind is to show the power of Repast in a lecture.)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The [Computational Model Library](https://www.comses.net) contains models from a variety of ABM modeling toolkits, including Repast Simphony. These come up if you search using "Repast" as a keyword.

Repast Simphony also comes with demonstration models (included in the macOS and Windows distributions or available [here](https://github.com/Repast/repast.simphony.models/archive/v.2.5.zip) as a standalone download), but those are more geared towards showing examples of how Repast Simphony features can be incorporated into user models. Have you looked at those?